# how to use C# HWNDs from Mono in a native Linux OpenGL environment?

Tags: opengl, mono

I have a C# gui with a c++ windows dll that does opengl stuff.  I want to run this under Linux with Mono, and am planning making the c++ dll into a true cross platform dll / .so with native Unix opengl initialization.

Instead of learning QT or WxWidgets, I want to continue to use the C# gui.  How do I use the windows form HWNDs that I currently pass to windows opengl glw and also pass them to Linux opengl glx and convert to Window object?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I use the windows form HWNDs that I currently pass to windows opengl glw and also pass them to Linux opengl glx and convert to Window object?

Uh, you don't/can't.

You'll have to implement two code paths, one covering GLX and one covering Windows GDI. Conceptually wgl and GLX are similar (wgl has been designed following GLX). But the internal data structures are very different.